# Did Ainz use Master Source to view the NPC list?

Tags: overlord

In season 1 episode 10 of *Overlord*, Ainz is able to view the NPC list.

I thought Ainz couldn't use the interface at all anymore.

Did he use the Master Source to view the NPC list? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

He does not use the Master Source, he merely uses a display associated with the Throne; Albedo has used it as well.